# Do you have to end in the same view file?

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra

Say if i started an if statement <% if .... %> in a header.erb view file, do i have to end that statement in the same file <% end %>, or can it be in a different view file, like footer.erb?

And when i do <% erb :"header" %> and <% erb :"footer" %> in my main view file, would that achieve the same thing as putting the if and end in the same file?

I tried the first one but its giving me this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bPIa.png)

For context im trying to implment a suspend functionality, where the if statement checks if a user is suspended when they log in, if they are then they wont have access to any of the pages

Comment: What's in the header line 16 and 21?

Comment: Yes, when you open an ERB block in a file then that block must close in the same file too. You cannot open a block in one file and have the closing tag in another. This is because the ERB code is evaluated before the strings (the return value of other included ERB files) are concatenated.

Comment: I don't believe you can, and in general it would be very bad practice and hard to debug, especially in the future when you've forgotten what you've done, or on projects where multiple people are collaborating